# Is there jitsi SIP-client for Ubuntu or Debian which has command-line interface?

Tags: command-line, sip

Is there jitsi SIP-client for Ubuntu or Debian which has command-line interface? So, for example, I can make calls without using jitsi GUI, just sending commands to the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can start jitsi from command line and it will start a call if you pass the uri of the contact. For example: jitsi xmpp:user@server.domain it will start the new call in existing jitsi if it is working. 
Little bug here - you can not pass an IP address after @, see https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/issues/471

Comment: If you want just a sip client take a look at `baresip` (linux only)

Comment: but **how** do you start `jitsi` from the console?

Comment: `java -jar jitsi.jar` or `"C:\Program Files\Jitsi\Jitsi.exe" sip:79250000000`

Comment: ah, but where do you download `jitsi.jar` from?

Comment: http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=jitsi.jar

Comment: I at least can't fine a .jar file

Answer (score 1):

Also there is another option https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi/pull/270 
*Adds a parameter to enable video on sip calling. You can call $jitsi sip:someaddr@domain.org?video=true.*